# Kotlin library 'classes.jar' has an unsupported format. Please update the library or the plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This message appears on project sync.

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project, but no success.

I'm using latest plugin version 0.12.275, "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.12.213" and "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.12.213"

I've tried with the stable version 0.12.200 for both plugin and library, but I get the same error.

I'm using Android Studio AI-141.1972460 (canary channel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in my *.aar lib, that was included in the project - it was compiled with an old version of Kotlin. I've upgraded the libary to the latest Kotlin version and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved with the updated library as mentioned by @ookami.kb

**About the error message...**

The "unsupported format" error comes when the ABI version number of the class files created by Kotlin does not match the expected used by the Kotlin compiler.  This is no longer an issue with Kotlin 1.0 Betas since the ABI number will not change again for 1.0.  But, there will be one forced recompile at 1.0 release candidate to ensure no old compiler bugs affect libraries or code and everything is rebuilt clean.  Afterwards no issues such as this will exist.

Therefore if a library is not up to date with the same ABI, or hits this last "1.0 recompile" you may run into a similar error.  The solution is always to find the updated library.

More about this in the [Kotlin 1.0 Beta 4 announcement](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/12/kotlin-1-0-beta-4-is-out/) "What's Next" section:

> After the Beta period is over, there will an RC and then 1.0.
>
> We would really like to make sure that no code compiled with
>   pre-release versions of Kotlin are kept around after 1.0, so the RC
>   compiler will force recompilation of all the old code. We will
>   coordinate with library maintainers outside JetBrains to make sure
>   that all the widely-used libraries will be recompiled in time.
>
> We’ll also take the opportunity to remove some legacy at this point:
>
> - remove all the deprecations that we have accumulated in the process of evolving our libraries,
> - remove all the deprecations from the generated code (you might not have heard of those, but they exist!),
> - get rid of some legacy bytecode peculiarities that were found during the beta,
> - move some of the stdlib code around so that the packages there have
>     more structure.
>
> After that point, the only compatible changes to the
>   standard library are deprecations and additions (this does not include
>   reflection APIs). We are running an open review for the library API to
>   make sure we haven’t missed anything important.

Answer (score -1):

This is Kotlin bug with new plugin version

Comment: This is not a bug, it is an assertion of the compiler to guarantee during Kotlin Alphas/Betas that code used together was compiled with the same internal class format.